# Non-essential imports compiled by javac

Tags: import, javac, java-compiler-api

Just verified that javac compiles every reference or import that it sees, such as JavaDoc @link references.

Can this be turned off with an argument?

And/or, can a less eager compile be implemented using the javax compiler API?

(I could blank out those references before feeding the source into the compiler, I guess, but I hope there are simpler ways.)

Answer (score 1):

`ecj` lets you choose whether or not javadoc tags should be analysed, the option is `-enableJavadoc`.

I don't know whether `javac` has a similar option.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that, although I'd looked into it('s voluminous source tree) before asking this question. Javadoc not enabled is doubtlessly the saner default. I guess javac is just lazily (in the implementation effort sense) following each import. Problem is that I would have to install that whole hunk of a library, although it has another great benefit: it can cope with partial errors. For now, I am getting past the problem  by having code that copies the source and comments out the useless imports.